# In App purchase is creating error

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I am creating an app which need to add In app Purchasing option to purchase selected video, and when purchased send request to download it on other server with Receipt; 
I am trying to achieve list of available option to purchase with the fallowing code--

```
try
{
    ListingInformation ProdList = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
    lbProductsList.Items.Clear();
    string t = "";

    foreach (var item in ProdList.ProductListings)
    {
        t = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2},{3}, {4}",
                            item.Key,
                            item.Value.Name,
                            item.Value.FormattedPrice,
                            item.Value.ProductType,
                            item.Value.Description);

        lbProductsList.Items.Insert(0, t);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);

}
```

code line-
 ListingInformation ProdList = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
its creating problem and control goes to catch block showing error message --

> The explicit transaction has been forcibly cancelled. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8032000F)

and when using registered Product Id it show the fallowing error--

```
System.Exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x805A0194
```

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at IAP.MainPage.d__1.MoveNext()

Would any one please tell what is the problem with it.
I am using registed App Id to load information but can't

any help is good for me.
Thanks.

Comment: "problem" is very general word, can you be more specific

Comment: catch block showing error message  The explicit transaction has been forcibly cancelled. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8032000F)

Comment: I want to know only what is the problem?it was working fine before few days.

Comment: @Abhishek , have you solved the problem ?

Comment: Not really, Problem solved automatically after few time.

Answer (score 2):

can you check your app guid in the WMAppManifest.xml file with guid in DevCenter published app guid? If not, make sure you should update your WMAppManifest.xml with guid from devcenter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created any in-app products in Dev Center associated with your app? Make sure the product id matches the product id in Dev Center for your main app that references these in-app products.
0x805A0194 is one of the exception errors you will get if the app could not get the products associated with the app and you have an internet connection.

Comment: Thanks, but there was problem with product created by client in Dev Center, when i corrected created another product in Dev center and there In app product and used new AppId then error removed and this is returning all product list.